# Proving a group homomorphism between two groups with different operations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Here is a rather simple algebra question: Suppose $(G,\star)$ and $(H,\circ)$ are groups and $\varphi$ is a map from $G\rightarrow H$. Am I correct in understanding that to show $\varphi$ is a homomorphism is to show that for any $g,h\in G$,
$$\varphi(g\star h) = \varphi(g)\circ\varphi(h),$$
e.g. the map factors with respect to the operation on $H$? Since most textbooks notate the operations in both groups by placing the symbols next to each other this is often written as 
$$\varphi(gh) = \varphi(g)\varphi(h),\ g,h\in G,$$
which is a bit confusing (for someone without much talent in mathematics, like me) until it is dissected...

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, you are correct. Often times, textbooks don't write it out in full the way you did in order to simplify notation, but you understand exactly what a homomorphism is.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism

Comment: Cheers folks! Looks like wiki is a bit better than wolfram here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupHomomorphism.html.

Comment: The reason that sometimes the notation is shortened is that it is usually clear form the context which operations one has in $G$ respectively in $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is what $\varphi(gh)=\varphi(g)\varphi(h)$ means. If writing the concrete binary operation makes it easier for you to understand what's going on, then there is no harm in writing it. Just be aware that many do not.

Comment: Thanks! For me this is just a matter of having to rewire neural pathways from childhood in some cases. In particular I was proving a number theoretic group was isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ and momentarily thought my proof did not work because my map did not factor into integer multiplication :-O. It is only when I dissected the definition of homomorphism that I realized factoring into integer addition was consistent with the claimed isomorphism. These are the little things that those of us not born to math stuggle with sometimes :-)